# Prevent or remove an extra Series Y-axis Point from being added to Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

How can I remove or prevent the '120' Y-axis Point from being added to my column Chart? I only want to show data within 0 to 100.

See screenshot below:
[image]

This is my code that creates the chart (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting):

```
        Chart chart = new Chart();

        string[] xAxis1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
        decimal[] yAxis1 = { 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 };
        string[] xAxis2 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
        decimal[] yAxis2 = { 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 };
        string[] xAxis3 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
        decimal[] yAxis3 = { 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 };

        chart.Series.Add("Benchmark");
        chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis1, yAxis1);
        chart.Series[0].Color = Color.Blue;

        chart.Series.Add("Current");
        chart.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis2, yAxis2);
        chart.Series[1].Color = Color.Maroon;

        chart.Series.Add("Recommended");
        chart.Series[2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(xAxis3, yAxis3);
        chart.Series[2].Color = Color.LawnGreen;

        // Chart area
        ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

        // Chart Legend
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        legend.Docking = Docking.Bottom;
        chart.Legends.Add(legend);

        // Chart Size
        chart.Size = new Size(500, 350);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;`

Comment: @jstreet That works thank you. TBH I was thinking of using that, but I assumed it was setting the height (in pixels) of the chart. Guess I should have tried it out first.

You should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind offer, but you can post it yourself in case you want to mark your question as answered.

Comment: You should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;` - jstreet.